# Не переведено сообщение об отклонении тревоги

Tags: дефект, статус-завершено, локализация

> flags should not be used to indicate technical inaccuracies, or an altogether wrong answer

Подробнее [в соседнем вопросе](/q/3259/178988).

Comment: не нашёл в transifex-е ничего подобного.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Спасибо за отзыв! Строка была добавлена и переведена (спасибо [@m0sa](https://stackoverflow.com/users/155005/m0sa)). Обновления будут доступны после ближайшей успешной сборки движка.